# gstreamer pipeline issue on imx6 yocto project?

Tags: c, gstreamer, gstreamer-0.10, gstreamer-1.0

I'm working on VVDN imx6 board I had successfully installed gstreamer on it.  After this command:

```
gst-launch-0.10 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

I got error:

> root@imx6slzbha:~# gst-launch-0.10 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert !
> autoaudiosink Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
>
> ERROR: Pipeline doesn't
> want to pause.
>
> ERROR: from element
> /GstAlsaSink:autoaudiosink0-actual-sink-alsa: Could not ope.
>
> Additional debug info:
> /home/user/vvdn_sdk/stct_iog1/source/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-m:
>
> Playback open error on device 'default': No such file or directory
> Setting pipeline to NULL ...
>
> Freeing pipeline ...

Comment: Check pipeline support enabled or disabled in kernel config.

Comment: but how can i check whether pipeline support is enabled or not on imx6 board? if you have any idea then please let me know.

Comment: use bitbake menuconfig command for that.

Comment: Thnx @Kanji Viroja for your replay....

Comment: I don't have bitbake menuconfig option but i have other three options.  1)bitbake gnu-config
  2)bitbake wmiconfig
  3)bitbake fontconfig, so first i will try these option and after successful build , flash that image on board and then try to execute same command ... If have any problem then i'll let you know...thnx ones again.

Comment: hello Kanji, I had try that solution but it's not working for me....after this try i got same error. If you have any other solution then please let me know.

Comment: There should be a ".config" file in your kernel build directory, that is the kernel config, open that and check for CONFIG_SND_SOC* options.

Comment: "Additional debug info: /home/user/vvdn_sdk/stct_iog1/source/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-m:" Could you please post the output of this logs here ? Additionally  for debugging runs as follows  1. export GST_DEBUG=5    2.gst-launch-0.10 audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink and check for error messages, you may also post it here so that anyone can see what the issue is

Comment: Can you please share a log file?

Comment: Hello Devarsh Thakkar, i tried that debugging and got same error. And also try to search for CONFIG_SND_SOC* in config file but i got these three PACKAGECONFIG_pn-qemu-native = "sdl" 
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-nativesdk-qemu = "sdl"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-gstreamer1.0-plugins-good = "vpx wavpack jack libv4l2" packages in local.conf file. I did not get any result related to CONFIG_SND_SOC*.

Comment: /home/user/vvdn_sdk/stct_iog1/source/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-mx6-poky-linux-gnueabi at this location I have several folders like cairo, gpu-viv-bin-mx6q, gst-plugins-base, libdrm, libfslcodec, libfslparser, libglu, libsdl, mesa, xserver-xorg and each folder contains it's own data...so which log file you want?